# How can I insert a Row by clicking on Hyperlink in VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

My code is not working, I am trying to insert a Row by clicking on Hyperlink and My hyperlink I am using + symbol...

```
     ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = "+"
       If ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1) <> "" Then
         ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(1, 1), _
         Address:=strString
       End If
```

This workbook.....

```
       Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
        If Target.Parent.Value = "+" Then Rows(Target.Parent.Row + 1).Insert
       End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Hyperlinks(1).Parent` as a Range
`Hyperlinks(1).Parent.Parent` as a Worksheet

So your code should be :

```
With ActiveSheet
    .Cells(1, 1).Value = "+"
    '''No need to test as you fill it yourself
    .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Cells(1, 1), Address:=strString
End If
```

Sheet's module :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    If Target.Parent.Value = "+" Then _
        Target.Parent.Parent.Rows(Target.Parent.Row + 1).Insert CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow
End Sub
```

or shorter :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    If Target.Parent.Value = "+" Then _
        Me.Rows(Target.Parent.Row + 1).Insert CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow
End Sub
```

---

I've added `CopyOrigin` parameter, to copy the format from the below row to avoid the reproduce the hyperlink style on the newly inserted row!

`CopyOrigin` takes either of one parameter as given below:

```
Const xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove = 0
Member of Excel.XlInsertFormatOrigin
```

and

```
Const xlFormatFromRightOrBelow = 1
Member of Excel.XlInsertFormatOrigin
```